# python: fix escaped unicode characters in data written to json file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I am having a problem with a program of mine.
I access google places api and get a json, parse it and get only the values I am interested in and write them to file. I have problem with the unicode characters in the response from google's api.
I am using python 2.7.13 running on Ubuntu 17.04.

The problem is that the API returns strings as:

> Museo Nacional Centro de Arte Reina Sofía

There is a special char: í

However in the file I find this:

> Museo Nacional Centro de Arte Reina Sof\u00eda

After getting the data from the request and using json.loads I get unicode strings in the dict and from there on they stay with the escaped chars.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import urllib2
import json

def getPlaces(category, country, city, url, token):
    requestURL = url.replace("CATEGORY", category)
    requestURL = requestURL.replace("CITY", city)

    if not (token is None):
        requestURL = requestURL + "&pagetoken=" + token

    jsonData = urllib2.urlopen(requestURL).read()
    data = json.loads(jsonData)
    result = []

    for item in data["results"]:
        result.append(getRowData(item, country, category))
    if "next_page_token" in data:
        nextToken = data["next_page_token"]
        result = result + getPlaces(category, country, city, url, nextToken)
    return result

def getRowData(item, country, category):
    lsit = []
    name = item["name"]
    lat = item["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = item["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    return [country, category, name, lat, lng]

# def listToStr(lst):
#   result = '[ '
#   if lst[0] is 

def_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=CATEGORY+in+CITY&key=NOKEY:)"

attractions = getPlaces("museum", "Spain", "Madrid", def_url, None)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(attractions, outfile)
```

I have read some things on the subject and info about the libs which I am using however I cannot fix this problem.

Comment: I rewrote it using Java and Google's gson lib but I am still curious how to fix this. :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try encode().decode() since `"Sof\u00eda".encode().decode()` works fine.

In your code, I would change the `getRowData` function like this:

```
def getRowData(item, country, category):
    lsit = []
    name = item["name"]
    lat = item["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = item["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    return [country.encode().decode(), category.encode().decode(), 
            name.encode().decode(), lat, lng]
```

Comment: Yeah tried this one before and I still get:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 39: ordinal not in range(128)